# Error: Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in --prod

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic3, node-modules

i am not sure i am facing an issue only with `ionic cordova run android --prod` and my `ionic cordova run android` works fine.

ERROR:

```
Error: Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in /Users/gopi/Documents/bos/hybrid-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/es2015/components/app/overlay-portal.d.ts! Add OverlayPortal to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class IonicApp in /Users/gopi/Documents/bos/hybrid-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/es2015/components/app/app-root.d.ts! Add IonicApp to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class ClickBlock in /Users/gopi/Documents/bos/hybrid-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/es2015/components/app/click-block.d.ts! Add ClickBlock to the NgModule to fix it.
Cannot determine the module for class Slides in /Users/gopi/Documents/bos/hybrid-app/node_modules/ionic-angular/es2015/components/slides/slides.d.ts! Add Slides to the NgModule to fix it.
```

Can some one give me clear explaination:

Here is my `ionic info`

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.11.1
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Comment: Try the usual, delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, run `npm install`, try to build again. If it still does not work try upgrading npm to a newer version (`5.1.0` works good for me) and do the same steps again. If still no success try upgrading the ionic-cli, ionic-angular and @ionic/app-scripts. In some cases reinstalling node may help.

Comment: Same problem running npm 5.5.1. Steps above don't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any luck solving this one?  I'm seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

I finally found a fix for this.  I had a few imports from `ionic-angular` that imported the nested component directly as opposed to importing from the top-level package export.  I'm guessing the prod AOT compiler didn't like having some imports from the top-level and some directly to the nested item.  An example for me is below.  My guess is you could choose either one of these approaches, but when mixing them the AOT compiler won't be happy.

**Good**

`import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';`

**Bad**

`import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular/components/loading/loading-controller';`

Comment: Thanks it helped me even if it was for a different reason :)

Comment: The problem is the way you import the component as stated in this response. Make sure you import the component from the full package, not only the file. Good job!

Comment: I love ionic but it is so full of this kind of stuff... god bless the internet

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to post this! This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 7):

This will help you to solve this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55832874/849870

i solve my problem. in my project i was using an outdated module, `ion-datepicker`
if you are also using same issue, here are some steps, you can follow and find your infected or outdated module.

**1. Step one:**

in your project find in all files
`from 'ionic-angular/`
word,

**2. Step Two:**

if you find this word like 
`import { xyz } from 'ionic-angular/xyz/abc'`

update or remove that module.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer ...Worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me. After you install all your components with npm i, install alone typescript version 2.8.1

```
npm install typescript@2.8.1
```

run build again

Comment: in my case, this will produce another error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.3.0 but 2.8.1 was found instead

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1451#issuecomment-415336809), remove **Page** interface reference. Change

```
let page: Page;
```

to

```
let page;
```

Comment: I changed it to "let page:any" and that fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

1) Search "Page" occurrences in your project and remove it.

Using Ubuntu or Mac terminal for quick search by taping  :

```
> grep -r ": Page" src/*
//then
> grep -r ":Page" src/*
```

Remove it like this:

```
//let page:Page;
//becomes 
let page;
//and remove the import in the top of the file
```

2) Search "ionic-angular/xxxxxx" occurrences in your project and remove it.

```
grep -r "from \'ionic-angular\/" src/*
```

If you are using "ionic-angular/xxxxxx" you have to change it to "ionic-angular" only go in the Ionic documentation and check your component:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#overview

Comment: My problem was the `ionic-angular/xxxxxx` imports and the search helped me find them quickly and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue then i changed my one of the ionic angular imports address.
previous it was

`import { AlertController } from "ionic-angular\umd\components\alert"`

and i changed it to

```
import { AlertController } from "ionic-angular"
```

now its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had backup of a module, i had

```
MyModule
|- MyModule.ts -> class MyModule {}
MyModuleOld
|- MyModule.ts -> class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after installing Diagnostic with

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/diagnostic@4
```

I revert back my package.json then remove and add android platform updated with

```
ionic cordova platform rm android && ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

And it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

--prod compile using aot. However, if you want to compile just for release use only --release flag but you loose out of the features of aot

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a Pipe I had created (lets name it "CustomPipe") and that I wasn't using so I hadn't declared it in my PipesModule.
I had 4 pipes, 3 of which I was using and declaring and exporting in PipesModule. But "CustomPipe" wasn't declared anywhere, so when I ran `ionic cordova build android --prod` I got the following error:

```
ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class CustomPipe in .../app/pipes/custom.pipe.ts! Add CustomPipe to the NgModule to fix it.
```

Since I wasn't using it, I just deleted it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

here is a fix that worked for me.

in app.module.ts, add this:

```
import { OverlayPortal } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/overlay-portal';
import { ClickBlock } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/click-block';
import {IonicApp as IonicAppRoot} from 'ionic-angular/components/app/app-root';

...


declarations: [
    ...

    OverlayPortal,
    IonicAppRoot,
    ClickBlock,
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me, but I finally solved it.

Simply imported `{OverlayPortal}` into `app.module.ts` as typescript toldme to do AND modified the url.

```
import { OverlayPortal } from "../../node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/overlay-portal.d";
```

Then added it to "declarations" in NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     OverlayPortal
```

Then run `ionic capacitor build android --prod` again and the error was gone.