# npm run ionic:build --prod giving strange error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I am trying to run `npm run ionic:build --prod`, it is giving me below errors:

> Error: Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d.ts!
>   Add OverlayPortal to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class IonicApp in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d.ts! Add
>   IonicApp to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class ClickBlock in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d.ts!
>   Add ClickBlock to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class Slides in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/slides/slides.d.ts! Add
>   Slides to the NgModule to fix it.

Now if I try to include it in `app.module.ts` using below code:

```
import { OverlayPortal } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OverlayPortal, //for aot compilation
```

on doing `ionic serve` the error I get after is -

> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\D\IONIC\quicktask\quicktask-web-froala\node_modules\ionic-angular\umd\components\app\overlay-portal.d.js'
>       at Error (native)

What do I do to build using `--prod` and run using `ionic-serve` without any bug.

### Edit

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { App, NavController,  IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule,IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular'; // removed IonicApp from here

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { NewtaskPage } from '../pages/newtask/newtask';
//import { DashboardPage } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import { TaskgivenPage } from '../pages/taskgiven/taskgiven';
import { MytaskPage } from '../pages/mytask/mytask';

import { CommunicationPage } from '../pages/communication/communication';


import { CommunicationgivenPage } from '../pages/communicationgiven/communicationgiven';
import { CommunicationreportPage } from '../pages/communicationreport/communicationreport';
import { GivencommunicationclosedPage } from '../pages/givencommunicationclosed/givencommunicationclosed';

import { TestPage } from '../pages/test/test';
import { LogoutPage } from '../pages/logout/logout';
import { MyclosedtaskPage } from '../pages/myclosedtask/myclosedtask';
import { GivenclosedtaskPage } from '../pages/givenclosedtask/givenclosedtask';
import { ReporttoPage } from '../pages/reportto/reportto';
import { SlidePage } from '../pages/slide/slide';


import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
//import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition';


import { Headers, Http, HttpModule ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';

import {Commopen} from '../pages/givencommunicationclosed/commopen';
import { Userimage } from '../pages/dashboard2/userimage';

import { MycommclosedPage } from '../pages/mycommclosed/mycommclosed';
import { Dashboard2Page } from '../pages/dashboard2/dashboard2';
import { MytaskuserwisePage } from '../pages/mytaskuserwise/mytaskuserwise';
import  { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { PaymentPage } from '../pages/payment/payment';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { InfoPage } from '../pages/info/info';
import { PerformancePage } from '../pages/performance/performance';
import { PopoverPage } from '../pages/communicationgiven/popover';
import { Updatepopup} from '../pages/communicationgiven/updatepopup';
import { TimelinePage } from '../pages/timeline/timeline';
import { Commpopup } from '../pages/timeline/commpopup';
import {SearchPage} from '../pages/search/search';
import {SuggestionPage} from '../pages/suggestion/suggestion';
import {Mytaskpopup} from '../pages/mytask/mytaskpopup';
import {Userwisepopup} from '../pages/mytaskuserwise/userwisepopup';
import {Taskgivenpopup} from '../pages/taskgiven/taskgivenpopup';
import {Reportpopup} from '../pages/reportto/reportpopup';
import {FollowerPage} from '../pages/follower/follower';
import {CommfollowerPage} from '../pages/commfollower/commfollower';
import { CommPage } from '../pages/comm/comm';
import {ReportsPage} from '../pages/reports/reports';
import { DashmodalPage } from '../pages/dashmodal/dashmodal';
import { Dashmodal1Page } from '../pages/dashmodal1/dashmodal1';
import { LabelPage } from '../pages/label/label';
import { SortPage } from '../pages/sort/sort';
import { SortuserwisePage } from '../pages/sortuserwise/sortuserwise';
import { LastseenPage } from '../pages/lastseen/lastseen';
import { MemolistPage } from '../pages/memolist/memolist';
import { OfcmemoPage } from '../pages/ofcmemo/ofcmemo';
import { CommadminPage } from '../pages/commadmin/commadmin';
import { AdminpcPage } from '../pages/adminpc/adminpc';

import {AiPage} from '../pages/ai/ai';
import { Autosize } from '../directives/autosize/autosize';

// Import Froala Editor.
import "froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js";
import { NoSanitizePipe } from '../pipes/no-sanitize/no-sanitize';

// Import Angular2 plugin.
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
import {Nl2BrPipeModule} from 'nl2br-pipe';
import {LinkyModule} from 'angular-linky';

//Search
import { SelectSearchableModule } from 'ionic-select-searchable';

// for ionic build --prod errors or aot compilation
// import { OverlayPortal } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d';
//import { IonicApp } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d';
//import { ClickBlock } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d';
//import { Slides } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/slides/slides.d';
import { FilterArrayPipe } from '../pages/dashboard2/filterpipe';
import {IonicPage, NavParams, Slides} from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  //  OverlayPortal, //for aot compilation
 //   IonicApp , //for aot compilation for app-root.d
  //  ClickBlock, //for aot compilation
  //  Slides, //for aot compilation
  IonicApp,
    FilterArrayPipe, //for aot compilation
    TimeAgoPipe,
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginPage,
    NewtaskPage,
   // DashboardPage,
    TaskgivenPage,
    MytaskPage,
    CommunicationPage,
    CommunicationgivenPage,
CommunicationreportPage,
GivencommunicationclosedPage,    
    TestPage,
    LogoutPage,
    MyclosedtaskPage,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    ReporttoPage,
    Dashboard2Page,
    MytaskuserwisePage,
    MycommclosedPage,
    ProfilePage,
    PaymentPage,
    InfoPage,
    SlidePage,
    PerformancePage ,
    PopoverPage,
    Updatepopup,
    SearchPage,
    TimelinePage,
    Commpopup,
    SuggestionPage,
    Mytaskpopup,
    Userwisepopup,
    Taskgivenpopup,
    Reportpopup,
    AiPage,
    Autosize,
    NoSanitizePipe,
    FollowerPage,
    CommfollowerPage,
    CommPage,
    ReportsPage,
    DashmodalPage,
    Dashmodal1Page,
    LabelPage,
    SortPage,
    SortuserwisePage,
    LastseenPage,
    MemolistPage,
    OfcmemoPage,
    CommadminPage,
    AdminpcPage,
    //OverlayPortal
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    Nl2BrPipeModule,
    LinkyModule,
    SelectSearchableModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(),
    FroalaViewModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginPage,
    NewtaskPage,
   // DashboardPage,
    TaskgivenPage,
    MytaskPage,
    CommunicationPage,
    CommunicationgivenPage,
    CommunicationreportPage, 
    GivencommunicationclosedPage,
    TestPage,
    LogoutPage,
    MyclosedtaskPage,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    ReporttoPage,
    Dashboard2Page,
    MytaskuserwisePage,
    MycommclosedPage,
    ProfilePage,
    PaymentPage,
    InfoPage,
    SlidePage,
    PerformancePage,
    PopoverPage,
    Updatepopup,
    SearchPage,
    TimelinePage,
    Commpopup,
    SuggestionPage,
    Mytaskpopup,
    Userwisepopup,
    Taskgivenpopup,
    Reportpopup,
    AiPage,
    FollowerPage,
    CommfollowerPage,
    CommPage,
    ReportsPage,
    DashmodalPage,
    Dashmodal1Page,
    LabelPage,
    SortPage,
    SortuserwisePage,
    LastseenPage,
    MemolistPage,
    OfcmemoPage,
    CommadminPage,
    AdminpcPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    //Firebase,
    Commopen,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    Userimage,
    InAppBrowser,
    SpeechRecognition,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: see [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-solve-app-script-issue/107429)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are using to import is the `type definitions` file with the extension `.d.js`.

You should import from the `.ts` file instead. Check the folder and you should get it

Comment: but i am not importing anything from this file, i have checked `app.component.ts` and `app.module.ts`

Comment: `import { OverlayPortal } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d';` This is your import

Comment: So you are importing `OverlayPortal` from this

Comment: i have copied `app.module.ts` above, that line is commented, i am not importing it

Comment: are you using OverlayPortal somewhere ?

Comment: Project is quite big with 3,4 developers, may be we tried to use it somewhere and that page is not being used now

Comment: Yes, so you need to remove that usage of OverlayPortal. Since it is not included in the module anymore

Comment: And incase, you want to import, you shouldn't use `.d` files

Comment: i did npm install again, it is now giving new error, have a look- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974616/ionic-serve-giving-error

Comment: Can you accept or upvote this question, bcoz the answer is helpful to you

Comment: You accepted and then unaccepted. The answer given correctly solves your problem. You just changed the question and unaccepted. This way, no one can help you. If there are multiple errors, you can ask again in different question. But you should accept previous answer

Comment: if you want me to just accept it, i will. But problem is not resolved, error is still there and nowhere i am using OverlayPortal in the project, all development team is here and we are acting as per your instructions, we are not finding it anywhere

Comment: As you said, its a huge module. Problems cannot be resolved with one answer. But the answer given to your first problem is correct and you should accept. And ask more questions if more issues

Comment: ACCEPTED, please see error , it is also asking for `app-root.d.ts` , why ?

Comment: Can we have a new question with one specific error ? Here its already too messy

Comment: here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976033/npm-run-ionicbuild-prod-error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169567/discussion-between-ashfaq-p-and-user2828442).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error.  For me it was due to inconsistent Ionic imports (some from top-level `ionic-angular`, and some importing directly from the component, e.g. `ionic-angular/components/loading/loading-controller`).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50858210/6599076

Answer (score 0):

Remove "umd" from the URL

```
import { OverlayPortal } from "../../node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/overlay-portal.d";
```

More here => [Error: Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in --prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599017/error-cannot-determine-the-module-for-class-overlayportal-in-prod/66583277#66583277)

Answer (score -2):

I solve my problem. In my project I was using an outdated module, `ion-datepicker`. if you are also using same issue, here are some steps you can follow and find your infected or outdated module.

**1. Step one:**

In your project find in all files
`from 'ionic-angular/`
word,

**2. Step two:**

If you find this word like 
`import { xyz } from 'ionic-angular/xyz/abc'`

update that module.

If no update available then you can remove that module

```
npm uninstall ion-datepicker(or your defected module)
```

After this you needs to remove that module from `app.module.ts` and where ever you are using remove from there, after that you can try

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`