# ionic serve giving error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I am trying to run my app, it is saying

> Type IonicApp is part of the declarations of 2 modules: IonicModule and AppModule! Please consider moving IonicApp to a higher module that imports IonicModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes IonicApp then import that NgModule in IonicModule and AppModule.

How do I get rid of this error ?

Copying entire error coming in console below:

> ionic-app-script task: "build"
>   [11:51:25]  Error: Type IonicApp in F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala -
>               test/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/app-root.d.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
>               IonicModule in F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala - test/node_modules/ionic-angular/module.d.ts and
>               AppModule in F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala - test/src/app/app.module.ts! Please consider moving
>               IonicApp in F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala -
>               test/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/app-root.d.ts to a higher module that imports IonicModule in
>               F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala - test/node_modules/ionic-angular/module.d.ts and AppModule in
>               F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala - test/src/app/app.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule
>               that exports and includes IonicApp in F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala -
>               test/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/app/app-root.d.ts then import that NgModule in IonicModule in
>               F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala - test/node_modules/ionic-angular/module.d.ts and AppModule in
>               F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala - test/src/app/app.module.ts.

What should I do?

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { App, NavController,  IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule,IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular'; // removed IonicApp from here

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { NewtaskPage } from '../pages/newtask/newtask';
//import { DashboardPage } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import { TaskgivenPage } from '../pages/taskgiven/taskgiven';
import { MytaskPage } from '../pages/mytask/mytask';

import { CommunicationPage } from '../pages/communication/communication';


import { CommunicationgivenPage } from '../pages/communicationgiven/communicationgiven';
import { CommunicationreportPage } from '../pages/communicationreport/communicationreport';
import { GivencommunicationclosedPage } from '../pages/givencommunicationclosed/givencommunicationclosed';

import { TestPage } from '../pages/test/test';
import { LogoutPage } from '../pages/logout/logout';
import { MyclosedtaskPage } from '../pages/myclosedtask/myclosedtask';
import { GivenclosedtaskPage } from '../pages/givenclosedtask/givenclosedtask';
import { ReporttoPage } from '../pages/reportto/reportto';
import { SlidePage } from '../pages/slide/slide';


import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
//import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition';


import { Headers, Http, HttpModule ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';

import {Commopen} from '../pages/givencommunicationclosed/commopen';
import { Userimage } from '../pages/dashboard2/userimage';

import { MycommclosedPage } from '../pages/mycommclosed/mycommclosed';
import { Dashboard2Page } from '../pages/dashboard2/dashboard2';
import { MytaskuserwisePage } from '../pages/mytaskuserwise/mytaskuserwise';
import  { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { PaymentPage } from '../pages/payment/payment';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { InfoPage } from '../pages/info/info';
import { PerformancePage } from '../pages/performance/performance';
import { PopoverPage } from '../pages/communicationgiven/popover';
import { Updatepopup} from '../pages/communicationgiven/updatepopup';
import { TimelinePage } from '../pages/timeline/timeline';
import { Commpopup } from '../pages/timeline/commpopup';
import {SearchPage} from '../pages/search/search';
import {SuggestionPage} from '../pages/suggestion/suggestion';
import {Mytaskpopup} from '../pages/mytask/mytaskpopup';
import {Userwisepopup} from '../pages/mytaskuserwise/userwisepopup';
import {Taskgivenpopup} from '../pages/taskgiven/taskgivenpopup';
import {Reportpopup} from '../pages/reportto/reportpopup';
import {FollowerPage} from '../pages/follower/follower';
import {CommfollowerPage} from '../pages/commfollower/commfollower';
import { CommPage } from '../pages/comm/comm';
import {ReportsPage} from '../pages/reports/reports';
import { DashmodalPage } from '../pages/dashmodal/dashmodal';
import { Dashmodal1Page } from '../pages/dashmodal1/dashmodal1';
import { LabelPage } from '../pages/label/label';
import { SortPage } from '../pages/sort/sort';
import { SortuserwisePage } from '../pages/sortuserwise/sortuserwise';
import { LastseenPage } from '../pages/lastseen/lastseen';
import { MemolistPage } from '../pages/memolist/memolist';
import { OfcmemoPage } from '../pages/ofcmemo/ofcmemo';
import { CommadminPage } from '../pages/commadmin/commadmin';
import { AdminpcPage } from '../pages/adminpc/adminpc';

import {AiPage} from '../pages/ai/ai';
import { Autosize } from '../directives/autosize/autosize';

// Import Froala Editor.
import "froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js";
import { NoSanitizePipe } from '../pipes/no-sanitize/no-sanitize';

// Import Angular2 plugin.
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
import {Nl2BrPipeModule} from 'nl2br-pipe';
import {LinkyModule} from 'angular-linky';

//Search
import { SelectSearchableModule } from 'ionic-select-searchable';

// for ionic build --prod errors or aot compilation
// import { OverlayPortal } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d';
//import { IonicApp } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d';
//import { ClickBlock } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d';
//import { Slides } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/slides/slides.d';
import { FilterArrayPipe } from '../pages/dashboard2/filterpipe';
import {IonicPage, NavParams, Slides} from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  //  OverlayPortal, //for aot compilation
 //   IonicApp , //for aot compilation for app-root.d
  //  ClickBlock, //for aot compilation
  //  Slides, //for aot compilation
  IonicApp,
    FilterArrayPipe, //for aot compilation
    TimeAgoPipe,
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginPage,
    NewtaskPage,
   // DashboardPage,
    TaskgivenPage,
    MytaskPage,
    CommunicationPage,
    CommunicationgivenPage,
CommunicationreportPage,
GivencommunicationclosedPage,    
    TestPage,
    LogoutPage,
    MyclosedtaskPage,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    ReporttoPage,
    Dashboard2Page,
    MytaskuserwisePage,
    MycommclosedPage,
    ProfilePage,
    PaymentPage,
    InfoPage,
    SlidePage,
    PerformancePage ,
    PopoverPage,
    Updatepopup,
    SearchPage,
    TimelinePage,
    Commpopup,
    SuggestionPage,
    Mytaskpopup,
    Userwisepopup,
    Taskgivenpopup,
    Reportpopup,
    AiPage,
    Autosize,
    NoSanitizePipe,
    FollowerPage,
    CommfollowerPage,
    CommPage,
    ReportsPage,
    DashmodalPage,
    Dashmodal1Page,
    LabelPage,
    SortPage,
    SortuserwisePage,
    LastseenPage,
    MemolistPage,
    OfcmemoPage,
    CommadminPage,
    AdminpcPage,
    //OverlayPortal
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    Nl2BrPipeModule,
    LinkyModule,
    SelectSearchableModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(),
    FroalaViewModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginPage,
    NewtaskPage,
   // DashboardPage,
    TaskgivenPage,
    MytaskPage,
    CommunicationPage,
    CommunicationgivenPage,
    CommunicationreportPage, 
    GivencommunicationclosedPage,
    TestPage,
    LogoutPage,
    MyclosedtaskPage,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    ReporttoPage,
    Dashboard2Page,
    MytaskuserwisePage,
    MycommclosedPage,
    ProfilePage,
    PaymentPage,
    InfoPage,
    SlidePage,
    PerformancePage,
    PopoverPage,
    Updatepopup,
    SearchPage,
    TimelinePage,
    Commpopup,
    SuggestionPage,
    Mytaskpopup,
    Userwisepopup,
    Taskgivenpopup,
    Reportpopup,
    AiPage,
    FollowerPage,
    CommfollowerPage,
    CommPage,
    ReportsPage,
    DashmodalPage,
    Dashmodal1Page,
    LabelPage,
    SortPage,
    SortuserwisePage,
    LastseenPage,
    MemolistPage,
    OfcmemoPage,
    CommadminPage,
    AdminpcPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    //Firebase,
    Commopen,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    Userimage,
    InAppBrowser,
    SpeechRecognition,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: can you include your **app.module.ts** in the question?

Comment: included, please have and look and guide

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to add IonicApp in declarations array which is what your error message seems to saying:

> Type IonicApp is part of the declarations of 2 modules: IonicModule and AppModule!

```
 declarations: [
  //  OverlayPortal, //for aot compilation
 //   IonicApp , //for aot compilation for app-root.d
  //  ClickBlock, //for aot compilation
  //  Slides, //for aot compilation
  IonicApp,// <-- remove this.
```

It should only be in bootstrap array.

Comment: isnt that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966666/npm-run-ionicbuild-prod-giving-strange-error question? please dont change the question to a different issue after people have answered it

Comment: please help on that question

Answer (score 1):

IonicApp is a component and already declared inside IonicModule and needed only for bootstrapping. It is not a component to be added into declarations.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  //  OverlayPortal, //for aot compilation
  //   IonicApp , //for aot compilation for app-root.d
  //  ClickBlock, //for aot compilation
  //  Slides, //for aot compilation
  IonicApp  ----> delete This line.
```