# Npm run ionic:build --prod error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I am trying to run `npm run ionic:build --prod`, it is giving me below errors:

> Error: Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d.ts!
>   Add OverlayPortal to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class IonicApp in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d.ts! Add
>   IonicApp to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class ClickBlock in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d.ts!
>   Add ClickBlock to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class Slides in
>   F:/D/IONIC/quicktask/quicktask-web-froala/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/slides/slides.d.ts! Add
>   Slides to the NgModule to fix it.

What do I do to build using `--prod`. I have done `npm install` again, updated app/scripts, don't know what else is needed.

**Find below my app.module.ts**

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { App, NavController,  IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule,IonicApp } from 'ionic-angular'; // removed IonicApp from here

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { NewtaskPage } from '../pages/newtask/newtask';
//import { DashboardPage } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import { TaskgivenPage } from '../pages/taskgiven/taskgiven';
import { MytaskPage } from '../pages/mytask/mytask';

import { CommunicationPage } from '../pages/communication/communication';


import { CommunicationgivenPage } from '../pages/communicationgiven/communicationgiven';
import { CommunicationreportPage } from '../pages/communicationreport/communicationreport';
import { GivencommunicationclosedPage } from '../pages/givencommunicationclosed/givencommunicationclosed';

import { TestPage } from '../pages/test/test';
import { LogoutPage } from '../pages/logout/logout';
import { MyclosedtaskPage } from '../pages/myclosedtask/myclosedtask';
import { GivenclosedtaskPage } from '../pages/givenclosedtask/givenclosedtask';
import { ReporttoPage } from '../pages/reportto/reportto';
import { SlidePage } from '../pages/slide/slide';


import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
//import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition';


import { Headers, Http, HttpModule ,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { TimeAgoPipe } from 'time-ago-pipe';

import {Commopen} from '../pages/givencommunicationclosed/commopen';
import { Userimage } from '../pages/dashboard2/userimage';

import { MycommclosedPage } from '../pages/mycommclosed/mycommclosed';
import { Dashboard2Page } from '../pages/dashboard2/dashboard2';
import { MytaskuserwisePage } from '../pages/mytaskuserwise/mytaskuserwise';
import  { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { PaymentPage } from '../pages/payment/payment';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { InfoPage } from '../pages/info/info';
import { PerformancePage } from '../pages/performance/performance';
import { PopoverPage } from '../pages/communicationgiven/popover';
import { Updatepopup} from '../pages/communicationgiven/updatepopup';
import { TimelinePage } from '../pages/timeline/timeline';
import { Commpopup } from '../pages/timeline/commpopup';
import {SearchPage} from '../pages/search/search';
import {SuggestionPage} from '../pages/suggestion/suggestion';
import {Mytaskpopup} from '../pages/mytask/mytaskpopup';
import {Userwisepopup} from '../pages/mytaskuserwise/userwisepopup';
import {Taskgivenpopup} from '../pages/taskgiven/taskgivenpopup';
import {Reportpopup} from '../pages/reportto/reportpopup';
import {FollowerPage} from '../pages/follower/follower';
import {CommfollowerPage} from '../pages/commfollower/commfollower';
import { CommPage } from '../pages/comm/comm';
import {ReportsPage} from '../pages/reports/reports';
import { DashmodalPage } from '../pages/dashmodal/dashmodal';
import { Dashmodal1Page } from '../pages/dashmodal1/dashmodal1';
import { LabelPage } from '../pages/label/label';
import { SortPage } from '../pages/sort/sort';
import { SortuserwisePage } from '../pages/sortuserwise/sortuserwise';
import { LastseenPage } from '../pages/lastseen/lastseen';
import { MemolistPage } from '../pages/memolist/memolist';
import { OfcmemoPage } from '../pages/ofcmemo/ofcmemo';
import { CommadminPage } from '../pages/commadmin/commadmin';
import { AdminpcPage } from '../pages/adminpc/adminpc';

import {AiPage} from '../pages/ai/ai';
import { Autosize } from '../directives/autosize/autosize';

// Import Froala Editor.
import "froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js";
import { NoSanitizePipe } from '../pipes/no-sanitize/no-sanitize';

// Import Angular2 plugin.
import { FroalaEditorModule, FroalaViewModule } from 'angular-froala-wysiwyg';
import {Nl2BrPipeModule} from 'nl2br-pipe';
import {LinkyModule} from 'angular-linky';

//Search
import { SelectSearchableModule } from 'ionic-select-searchable';

// for ionic build --prod errors or aot compilation
// import { OverlayPortal } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d';
//import { IonicApp } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d';
//import { ClickBlock } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d';
//import { Slides } from '../../node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/slides/slides.d';
import { FilterArrayPipe } from '../pages/dashboard2/filterpipe';
import {IonicPage, NavParams, Slides} from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  //  OverlayPortal, //for aot compilation
 //   IonicApp , //for aot compilation for app-root.d
  //  ClickBlock, //for aot compilation
  //  Slides, //for aot compilation
  IonicApp,
    FilterArrayPipe, //for aot compilation
    TimeAgoPipe,
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginPage,
    NewtaskPage,
   // DashboardPage,
    TaskgivenPage,
    MytaskPage,
    CommunicationPage,
    CommunicationgivenPage,
CommunicationreportPage,
GivencommunicationclosedPage,    
    TestPage,
    LogoutPage,
    MyclosedtaskPage,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    ReporttoPage,
    Dashboard2Page,
    MytaskuserwisePage,
    MycommclosedPage,
    ProfilePage,
    PaymentPage,
    InfoPage,
    SlidePage,
    PerformancePage ,
    PopoverPage,
    Updatepopup,
    SearchPage,
    TimelinePage,
    Commpopup,
    SuggestionPage,
    Mytaskpopup,
    Userwisepopup,
    Taskgivenpopup,
    Reportpopup,
    AiPage,
    Autosize,
    NoSanitizePipe,
    FollowerPage,
    CommfollowerPage,
    CommPage,
    ReportsPage,
    DashmodalPage,
    Dashmodal1Page,
    LabelPage,
    SortPage,
    SortuserwisePage,
    LastseenPage,
    MemolistPage,
    OfcmemoPage,
    CommadminPage,
    AdminpcPage,
    //OverlayPortal
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    Nl2BrPipeModule,
    LinkyModule,
    SelectSearchableModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    FroalaEditorModule.forRoot(),
    FroalaViewModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginPage,
    NewtaskPage,
   // DashboardPage,
    TaskgivenPage,
    MytaskPage,
    CommunicationPage,
    CommunicationgivenPage,
    CommunicationreportPage, 
    GivencommunicationclosedPage,
    TestPage,
    LogoutPage,
    MyclosedtaskPage,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    ReporttoPage,
    Dashboard2Page,
    MytaskuserwisePage,
    MycommclosedPage,
    ProfilePage,
    PaymentPage,
    InfoPage,
    SlidePage,
    PerformancePage,
    PopoverPage,
    Updatepopup,
    SearchPage,
    TimelinePage,
    Commpopup,
    SuggestionPage,
    Mytaskpopup,
    Userwisepopup,
    Taskgivenpopup,
    Reportpopup,
    AiPage,
    FollowerPage,
    CommfollowerPage,
    CommPage,
    ReportsPage,
    DashmodalPage,
    Dashmodal1Page,
    LabelPage,
    SortPage,
    SortuserwisePage,
    LastseenPage,
    MemolistPage,
    OfcmemoPage,
    CommadminPage,
    AdminpcPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    //Firebase,
    Commopen,
    GivenclosedtaskPage,
    Userimage,
    InAppBrowser,
    SpeechRecognition,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My ionic info:

> cli packages: (C:\Users\jessica\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 5.0.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.10.3
npm               : 5.4.2
OS                : Windows 8.1
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Comment: import { SlidePage } from '../pages/slide/slide';  is this page lazy loaded (means is it having its own module) ?

Comment: it is a normal page named `export class SlidePage {` , none of my pages have `pagename.module.ts` file, i have deleted all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with AOT build is that, you have many plugins which are outdated and do not support AOT compilation.

In order to optimize, you can check for GZIP. This should reduce your load time significantly. GZIP needs to be done from server side and has nothing to do with your Frontend code.